# Add XML document as child to another node in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a question: I'm getting in Javascript XML. I want to add a 'father' node
to that xml.
How do I do that?

```
/* Load the XML text from the text area to a Javascript XML object */
var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmlDoc.async = "false";
xmlDoc.loadXML(taData.innerText);
xmlObj = xmlDoc.documentElement;        

/* Creating the Screen node */
var Screen = document.createElement("Screen");
Screen.setAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
Screen.setAttribute("xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "../../GUIGenerator_V2/Scheme/GG_Scheme.xsd");

/* Creating the Legend node */
var Legend = document.createElement("Legend");
Legend.setAttribute("EntityType", "Request");

var ImportedNode = document.adopteNode(xmlDoc.documentElement);
Legend.appendChild(ImportedNode);
Screen.appendChild(Legend);
```

Legend is the child of Screen, And I want to make the xmlDoc a child of Legend.

I have tried to write: Legend.appendChild(xmlDoc.documentElement);
but getting an error. What can be the problem?

Comment: Could you provide some example code? Did you already parse the XML into a `XMLDocument`? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: That does not seem to make sense to me... a document cannot be the child of a node. Either you add the root of the document as child or you serialize the document and set it as content of `Legend` (as a string).

Comment: how do I add the root element?

Comment: Can some one help me solving this?

Answer (score 1):

In some case, a XML is reference as a DOM inside JavaScript so you can use standard DOM functions on it. Pay attention about navigator specific implementation to avoid compatibility problems...

To add a father node you need to use something like :

```js
/* Load the XML text from the text area to a Javascript XML object */
    var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async = "false";
    xmlDoc.loadXML(taData.innerText);
    xmlObj = xmlDoc.documentElement;        

    /* Creating the Screen node */
    var Screen = document.createElement("Screen");
    Screen.setAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    Screen.setAttribute("xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "../../GUIGenerator_V2/Scheme/GG_Scheme.xsd");

    /* Creating the Legend node */
    var Legend = document.createElement("Legend");
    Legend.setAttribute("EntityType", "Request");

    var ImportedNode = document.adopteNode(xmlDoc.documentElement);    
    Legend.appendChild(ImportedNode);
    Screen.appendChild(Legend);
```

after execution of that code you obtain a document strucured like:

```
<fathernode>
  <YOURXMLDOCUMENT />
</fathernode>
```

Comment: I have tried to write:
Legend.appendChild(xmlDoc.documentElement);

Comment: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: I have copied to code I'm trying to run to the original message

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, Why do you create the 'legend' element twice?

Comment: I have updated the code I'm trying to run, but still getting the same error

Comment: And also, I'm still in the same document, so I don't think there is a need to adopt the XML document.

Comment: Can some one help me solving this?

Comment: Have you tried the adopt method... I don't understand how your xmlDoc variable can be the same document than the current HTML Document. Did you get the same error?